# Best layout for this product database?

Tags: mysql, database, product

I'm putting together an ecommerce site for a client with a fairly complex pricing scheme.  I've chosen to use foxycart, and have all product prices dynamically come out of a database.  The reason for this is that every customer gets different prices for products for single units, and for varying quantities purchased.  I'm trying to build the most flexible system I can, but I'm not sure what is best.

firstly I'll have a customer_table
with:

```
id, name, city, state, country, zip, phone
```

Next is where I'm trying to decide how to build things.  Right now there are 18 or so unique products, and some of these come in different sizes/volumes and have unique price break points per product, per size.  So one product would have a price for less than 4 purchased, another for less than 10, another for less than 19, and another for greater than 20, and difference prices for the same product but at a different size.  These price break points are not standard across all products either.  Some may have price breaks at 3,9,12, while others may have less than 5 and greater than 5.  The best way can think is just to build a table with 50 columns listing all these out.  None of the data repeats, since it will change depending on the cust_id, so it seems normalised to me, but I'm wondering what you all think.  This table might look like this:

```
id, cust_id, product1_lt4, product1_lt20, product1_gt20, product2_lt6, product2_lt12, product2_lt60, product2_gt60, etc...
```

With lt and gt being less than/greater than obviously.  It just gets so huge.

I was trying to break up the tables as much as possible having a Category_table, Sub Category_table, product_table, size_table, and price table but I can't think of any good way of inputting the data without having loads of null fields or 50+ tables.

Let me know if this makes sense.  I can provide more detail if needed.  I guess my main question is, is it a bad idea to go with option 1?

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me" site. If you have a specific coding question, ask it. This however is a "whiteboard" type question and not suited to here. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: 50+ tables isn't bad, or really a lot by any objective measure. Especially since there isn't going to be much/any coupling between the pricing information tables and the rest of your schema.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  @Bohemian, I wasn't really asking anyone to do any work for me.  I thought my question was pretty black and white to be honest.  Am I asking for trouble with option 1.  Then I provided my alternative schema for reference.  Sorry if you felt it doesn't make the cut.  I'll be more stringent in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might go with something like this:

```
Customers
id,first_name,etc...

Categories
id,name,etc...

Sub_Categories
id,name

Category_Sub_Categories
category_id,sub_category_id

Product_Categories
product_id,category_id

Product_Sub_Categories
product_id,sub_category_id

Products
id,name

Customer_Product_Prices
customer_id,product_id,quantity,price
```

Then you can just assume that the lowest quantity associated with a product is for any amount less than, and the greatest quantity price is for any quantity over

I believe this would be the most flexible and scalable way to build something with the complexity that you are trying to achieve

Comment: This is what I was thinking.  The prices will also need the customer id to link the two together, but the rest all makes sense.

Comment: Do customers order products at prices unique to them, or do customers create orders?

Comment: Pricing terms are negotiated with each customer based on how much they order and plan to order in the future.  The prices are unique to each customer, although there is a base price for each product that is used for many customers.  Customer 1 might pay $35 per unit scaling to $24 per unit at orders greater than 20.  Customer 2 might start at $31 per unit scaling to 19.50 for orders greater than 20.  There are many combinations of prices for volumes and products and customers.

Comment: I edited my answer to show the proper table structure for that type of setup.

Answer (score 1):

The Complete database should be :

Product Info

```
categories 
categories_description 
product_type_layout * 
product_types * 
product_types_to_category * 
products * 
products_attributes * 
products_attributes_download * 
products_description * 
products_discount_quantity * 
products_options * 
products_options_types 
products_options_values * 
products_options_values_to_products_options * 
products_to_categories * 
manufacturers 
manufacturers_info 
meta_tags_products_description 
meta_tags_categories_description 
reviews * 
reviews_description *
```

Sales/Special Pricing Details

```
featured 
salemaker_sales * 
specials *
```

Product Type Extra Information

```
media_clips 
media_manager 
media_to_products 
media_types 
music_genre 
product_music_extra * 
record_artists * 
record_artists_info * 
record_company * 
record_company_info *
```

CMS / Content Management

```
ezpages
```

Customer Information

```
address_book 
customers 
customers_info
```

Customers Stored Shopping Carts

```
customers_basket 
customers_basket_attributes
```

Customer Interaction

```
email_archive 
group_pricing 
products_notifications
```

Order History

```
files_uploaded 
orders * 
orders_products * 
orders_products_attributes * 
orders_products_download * 
orders_status_history 
orders_total *
```

and

```
paypal * 
paypal_payment_status_history * 
paypal_session *
```

PayPal™

```
paypal * 
paypal_payment_status 
paypal_payment_status_history * 
paypal_session * 
paypal_testing *
```

Admin Audit Trail

```
admin_activity_log 
authorizenet 
banners_history 
counter 
counter_history * 
coupon_email_track 
coupon_redeem_track 
email_archive
```

Coupon and Gift Certificate Config/Tracking

```
coupon_email_track 
coupon_gv_customer 
coupon_gv_queue 
coupon_redeem_track 
coupon_restrict 
coupons 
coupons_description
```

System Configuration

```
admin 
address_format 
configuration * 
configuration_group 
layout_boxes 
template_select * 
currencies 
languages
```

Tax/Zone Configuration

```
geo_zones 
tax_classes * 
tax_rates * 
zones_to_geo_zones * 
zones * 
countries
```

Other

```
banners 
banners_history 
get_terms_to_filter 
newsletters 
project_version * 
project_version_history * 
query_builder * 
db_cache 
sessions * 
upgrade_exceptions * 
whos_online *
```

for more see [here](http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Developers_-_Database_Schema)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Reading some of the wiki now.

Answer (score 0):

"I guess my main question is, is it a bad idea to go with option 1?"

Yes, it is a bad idea.  You've bound business logic directly into your schema, which means that if someone later decides that a price break for less than 6 items (for example) is desirable, you have to hand-modify your schema and application to support it.

Without more information as to your requirements and data structure it's hard to suggest a schema for you, but as a general guideline I'd suggest using a many-to-many link between your product table and a pricing table.  Such a structure would allow you to add new price categories relatively easily and avoid the brittle schema your option 1 implements.